# Change Read/Write permissions from command line or VB script without cacls

Tags: permissions, windows-xp-embedded

I need a way to automatically change the read/write permissions on a folder, on an Windows XP Embedded machine.

The XPE image I'm using doesn't have all of the standard Windows tools, and apparently cacls is one of those tools that it doesn't have.

If I simply type `cacls` into my command window, it tells me

> 'cacls' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Is there a way for me to change file/folder permissions in Windows XPE without the CACLS command, or is there a way I can download a version of cacls.exe that will run on the XPE machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try xcacls.vbs.

As stated [here](http://ss64.com/nt/xcacls.html):

> **xcacls.vbs** is described in [Q825751](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=825751) and can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ad33a24-0616-473c-b103-c35bc2820bda&DisplayLang=en)
>
> **xcacls.vbs** is an **unsupported utility** that addresses a limitation with the original xcacls.exe, specifically the inability to append permissions to a folder whose child objects have the inheritance flag set. The .vbs version does not suppport unc paths and is very slow to update multiple ACLs.

From the KB resource, it seems the VB script is independent of there existing CACLS or XCACLS on the system, but as I've strong-ed before, it is an unsupported utility.

Also in that page, XCACLS is part of the Windows Resource Kit; searching online for it might give you a way to download it and afterwards use the *real* XCACLS.exe